# In ASP.NET MVC, the ProcessRequest in my own MyHttpHanler just cannot be fired

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add some Routing rule in Global.ascx im my ASP.NET MVC application. I extend the `IRouteHanlder`, `MVCHandler` and `registe` the rule just as follow.

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    "DefaultTT", // Route name
        //    "test", // URL with parameters
        //    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        //);

        RouteValueDictionary defaults = new RouteValueDictionary();
        RouteValueDictionary constraints = new RouteValueDictionary();
        RouteValueDictionary tokens = new RouteValueDictionary();

        defaults.Add("controller", "home");
        defaults.Add("action", "index");
        defaults.Add("data", string.Empty);
        constraints.Add("data", @"[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*");
        tokens.Add("pageId", 0);

        routes.Add(new Route("", defaults, constraints, tokens, new MyRouteHandler()));
    }
public class MyRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {

        public System.Web.IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            return new MyMVCHanlder(requestContext);
        }
    }

    public class MyMVCHanlder : MvcHandler
    {
        public MyMVCHanlder(RequestContext requestContext)
            : base(requestContext)
        {

        }

        protected override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            int i = 1;
            int j = i + 1;
            base.ProcessRequest(httpContext);
        }


        protected override void ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            int i = 1;
            int j = i + 1;
            base.ProcessRequest(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

But when I visit localhost:50112/ in my browser, the ProcessRequest method cannot be fired. I don't know why. Do you have any thought? Thank you.

Comment: What do you get when you navigate browser to that url?

Comment: When I am trying to debug, I can see that the construct method of MyMVCHandler can be executed, that means the request will be handled by MyMVCHandler, but it never fire any ProcessRequest method. Do you know why?

Comment: is this a similar problem as this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13593114/1236044