# IHTTPHandler on Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ihttphandler

I try to use an existing `IHttpHandler` on an `ASP.NET MVC\WEB API` website, deployed on a `VS IIS EXPRESS 8.0` and on a production `IIS 7.5`

It basically looks like

```
public class MP4DownloadHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    ...

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        this.InternalRequestedFileInfo = this.GetRequestedFileInfo(context);
        this.InternalRequestedFileEntityTag = this.GetRequestedFileEntityTag(context);
        this.InternalRequestedFileMimeType = this.GetRequestedFileMimeType(context);

        ...
     }

     ...
 }
```

I want it to handle requests to urls ending with `.mp4`

I registered the `MP4DownloadHandler` in `web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />

      <add name="MP4DownloadHandler" verb="*" path="*.mp4" type="MP4DownloadHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>


      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

and also added ignore rules to the routing table for MVC and WEB API routing engines

in `MVC` `Register()`:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute(
    "get/GetImage/{fileName}",
    new { fileName = @".*\.mp4" }
);
```

in `WEB API`    `RegisterRoutes()`

```
config.Routes.IgnoreRoute(
    routeName: "Ignoremp4WebApi",
    routeTemplate: "get/GetImage/{fileName}",
    constraints: new { fileName=@".*\.mp4" }
);
```

When I try to make a get request with a url:

```
localhost:6032/get/GetImage/test.mp4
```

I get the following response:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8888
Request URL:http://localhost:6032/get/GetImage/test.mp4
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

<Error>
    <Message>
        No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:6032/get/GetImage/test.mp4'.
    </Message>
    <MessageDetail>No route data was found for this request.</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

In debug I see that my `ProcessRequest` was not called, so I can conclude that it's not the case that the handler doesn't find the file.

Is there anything special to be done in order to make IHttpHadlers work with MVC?

Comment: you can actually configure routes to use `IHttpHandlers` by implementing `IRouteHandler` and registering it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593114/custom-httphandler-and-routehandler-with-aspnet-mvc-4-and-webapi